# join to most recent right hand record, but place NULL when right table doesn't have data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am trying to build a view/query that hops across multiple joins showing one result row per left hand record, with the right hand record being the most recently-created record for that object in the table.

the end goal is to provide data to a front end application, but i need to be able to tell if there is no data in the right hand table while still displaying the data from the left hand table.

i don't know if i've worded that well; i'm a little out of my depth. maybe code will illustrate better than english. here are some tables to illustrate:

left hand table `bill`

```
id    description    extId
1     Some descr...  SB 123
2     Another de...  SB 124
3     Third desc...  SB 125
```

join table `tally_bill`

```
id    billId    tallyId
1     2         1
2     2         2
3     3         3
4     3         4
```

note that there is **no** entry for billId = 1

right hand table `tally`

```
id    countYes    countNo   created
1     4           0         2022-09-26 13:11:48
2     5           8         2022-09-26 14:50:24
3     10          11        2022-09-26 11:20:01
4     4           3         2022-09-26 13:41:25
```

my desired result looks something like this:

```
billId    description    extId    countYes    countNo
1         Some descr...  SB 123   null        null
2         Another de...  SB 124   5           8
3         Third desc...  SB 125   4           3
```

i need `countYes` and `countNo` to be the values from the most recently-created record in `tally`.

the query i've gotten so far is:

```
SELECT
    bill.id, bill.description, bill.extId,
    tally.id, tally.countYes, tally.countNo
FROM
    bill
LEFT JOIN tally_bill
    ON tally_bill.billId = bill.id
LEFT JOIN tally
    ON tally.id = tb.tallyId
    AND (
    SELECT
        MAX(tally.id)
    FROM
        tally_bill tb
    WHERE
        tb.billId = bill.id);
```

but this produces something to the effect of:

```
billId    description    extId    id    countYes    countNo
2         Another de...  SB 124   2     5           8
3         Third desc...  SB 125   4     4           3
```

as you see the record `billId = 1` is missing. i have made a few variations on this query moving the subquery around, trying group bys and partitions, etc., to no avail. i'm at the limit of my SQL-fu, so i would appreciate any help or enlightenment, please :)

i'm using MySQL 8.0.30 but if there is a need to change versions i'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select    id
         ,description
         ,extId
         ,countYes
         ,countNo
from     (
         select   b.id
                 ,b.description
                 ,b.extId
                 ,t.countYes
                 ,t.countNo
                 ,row_number() over(partition by b.id order by t.id desc) as rn
         from     bill b left join tally_bill tb on tb.billId = b.id left join tally t on t.id = tb.tallyId
         ) t
where    rn = 1
```

| id | description | extId | countYes | countNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Some descr | SB 123 | null | null |
| 2 | Another de | SB 124 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | Third desc | SB 125 | 9 | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u9_syeOF)

Comment: fantastic! that did the trick :) thank you very much! is there a name for this technique/pattern?

Comment: @niko I don't know about a name but you use `row_number` order by desc to get the last instance and then choose `rn = 1`.